# How can we identify layer two device in a network or what are those device effects on a frame

Tags: routing, switch, security, layer2

This is sample of a traceroute to google.com:

```
TraceRoute from Network-Tools.com to 216.58.194.46 [google.com]
Hop (ms)    (ms)    (ms)             IP Address Host name
1     0       0       0          206.123.64.233   -  
2     Timed out       Timed out       Timed out               -  
3     1       1       1          4.68.70.166     google-level3-3x10g.dallas.level3.net  
4     1       1       1          108.170.240.129      -  
5     1       1       1          209.85.242.53    -  
6     1       1       1          216.58.194.46   dfw25s12-in-f14.1e100.net  

Trace complete
```

It should be many **layer 2 network device** from our source to destination, that is not visible but They  have an important impact on the result; these layer 2 of the network devices have many roles, including security issue like **Span**, **Tap**, **deep packet inspection** or any other security usage or just a **layer 2 switche**. You can see some hop counts in the traceroute results, but there are certainly many L2 devices in the middle and I am looking for theory or practical way to find an answer to this question.

Comment: Layer-2 is local. Layer-2 information is completely lost at each layer-3 connection, and many layer-2 devices, e.g. ethernet switches are transparent devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just adding to Stuggi's fine answer: layer 2 has no TTL concept, so there's no way to build a `traceroute`-like tool for hop-by-hop analysis.

> How can we identify layer two device in a network or what are those device effects on a frame?

You can't **identify** an L2 device, at least not with a generic tool like `traceroute` and definitely not without device access.

There are vendor-specific tools that allow you to check L2 connectivity and display potential paths, based on the device configurations (usually read by SNMP).

Some L2 devices identify themselves using LLDP or CDP but I'm not sure if that helps you.

Any L2 device adds some **delay** to the forwarded frame, depending on the device and possibly on its configuration. Common delays are between 1 and 10 µs.

Also, depending on the device configuration, a device like a switch can add, remove, or change **frame tags** like 802.1Q (used for VLAN ID and priority (PCP)) but won't touch the rest of the frame. Likewise, even an L2 device may change the IP packet's **DSCP** but won't touch anything else.

Comment: Then the short answer is "you can't", at least not without a vendor-specific tool that simulates the path based on the device configs.

Comment: Maybe not yet but it should be possible, by analyzing of the effect of L2 net Devices on a packet we can find a clue to begin, like "latency" .every such that device has effects on the packet.

Comment: @R1w An L2 device like a switch doesn't make *any* change to a forwarded frame*, especially not to the packet inside the frame. Of course you could track a frame's progress by setting up a bunch of mirroring ports. (* Switches might change the 802.1Q and other tags when they're used but they don't touch the core frame.)

Comment: To add to your comment, I should mention that i tried to find my answer in a lab and till now I just find out that L2 dev has latency effect, it is because of the processing procedure.

Comment: Any forwarding device (or even a cable) adds some delay. I'm not sure how you want to use that though...

Comment: I did model a pattern for network device latency in lab env and yes there is the difference between cable latency and router, I don't have the complete answer but I am working on it.

Comment: Obviously, a buffering device (depending on its hardware) adds a much higher delay than a simple cable (depending on its length). A router is an L3 device though and you were very specific on asking about L2.

Comment: Do note that the latency effect of a switch is very small compared to a routing device, since switching is done with ASICs purpose-built to just switch ethernet frames. If memory serves, there's also some speciality switches that uses a technique called cut-through switching with extremely low latency (tens of nanoseconds). Routers, firewalls etc. add a lot more delay since they actually process the frame.

Comment: I actually have a supposedly completely transparent IPS in the lab, I need to see if there's any way of detecting it based on the frames flowing in and out.

Comment: @Stuggi If it's really transparent (to layer 2) you can't, by definition.

Answer (score 6):

Traceroute is a Layer3 technology, aka. by it's very design it'll never show anything else than the routers in path to the specific host. Traceroute works by sending packets with decreasing TTL, thus making every router in the path respond with a message say that the TTL value has been exceeded.

Switches live in L2, so they have no concept about what's in the frames containing the traceroute packets, they just forward them appropriately so that they reach the correct next hop router.

IPS:es are usually also designed so that they sit out of band, and only extract packets that they don't like. As such, they will never respond with anything to a host sending the packets, they just drop the packets if they match a specific filter rule.

Comment: Well, you started the question of with the output of traceroute, so I ran with it. :)